# Not able to get the map passed on the function properly in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
def parallelIntegrationTests(stages) {
def tests = stages.collectEntries{ stagename, config ->
    config = [solr: true, failonerror: true]
    [(stagename): {
        stage(stagename) {
            node('integration && php7.1') {
                ws('/var/lib/jenkins/shared-workspace/in-integration') {
                    try {
                        if (config.solr) {
                            sh "/usr/bin/ant -buildfile in/build.xml -Dphpunit.integration.group=${stagename} -Dphpunit.integration.failonerror=${config.failonerror} integration"
                        } else {
                            sh "/usr/bin/ant -buildfile in/build.xml integration-functional"
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        throw e
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
parallel tests
```

}

```
parallelIntegrationTests(
                        [
                                'integration-functional': {solr: false},
                                'security-authentication': {},
                                'api-infra': {},
                                'external-dependencies': {failonerror: false},
                                'registration': {}
                        ]
                )
```

I'm trying to handle the if else condition based on the parameter send from the function. But When ever the jenkinsfile is running and the parallelIntegrationTests is called, config parameter "config = [solr: true, failonerror: true]" set locally is overriding the parameter send from the calling fuction. How do I handle this?

Comment: 1 - your map is incorrect: should be `[solr:false]` instead of `{solr:false}`. 2 - it's not clear what you are asking about `How do I handle this?`...

Comment: @daggett Thanks This helps.

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is :

```
def parallelIntegrationTests(stages) {
def tests = stages.collectEntries{ stagename, config ->
config = [solr: true, failonerror: true] + config
[(stagename): {
    stage(stagename) {
        node('integration && php7.1') {
            ws('/var/lib/jenkins/shared-workspace/in-integration') {
                try {
                    if (config.solr) {
                        sh "/usr/bin/ant -buildfile in/build.xml -Dphpunit.integration.group=${stagename} -Dphpunit.integration.failonerror=${config.failonerror} integration"
                    } else {
                        sh "/usr/bin/ant -buildfile in/build.xml integration-functional"
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    throw e
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

}
parallel tests